# Error all browsers but Firefox trying to change background image with d3.js

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I get a wired error which I ca not understand.

I place a background-image (svg-file) in a div with CSS. I use this SVG to generate a Sprite animation which will work quite well.

```
.runner {
        background: url("0804_0537_Runner_sf-24.svg") no-repeat;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 30px;
        height: 40px;
        animation: walk 0.4s steps(18) infinite;
        animation-play-state: paused;

    }
```

The background image will be loaded in all browsers at the beginning. But when I try to change the background image afterwards with d3.js

```
var animatedicon = "0805_0537_Runner_sf-24.svg"; 
d3.selectAll('.runner')
                .transition()
                .delay(1000)
                .style('background', 'url('+animatedicon+') no-repeat');
```

all browsers but FireFox throw an error. Here is the console log from Chrome:

```
GET file:///Volumes/.../804.9576754956776_536.9717661381104_Runner_sf-23.99873815142393svg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
GET file:///Volumes/.../805_537_Runner_sf-24svg net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

It is not problem to load the file diectly in DOM with an `<object>`, too. How do I get 3D.js to replace the right URL without filling wired numbers between the name or forgetting the first `0` of the name and the file type dot(!) `...24svg` ?

Comment: it looks like that other browser see a floating point number within your filename, that's a funny one :D

Comment: @MaxouMask the funny one took me half an hour as I checked for anything else but floating numbers being parsed :D. But it seems it is related to d3.js only as it only happens when the script computes the URL...

Answer (score 0):

O.K. it seems like a bug in d3.js which is related to the **numbers** in the file name(!).

As soon as I change the names from 0804_0537_Runner_sf-24.svg to e.g. **Runnerstart.svg** and 0805_0537_Runner_sf-24.svg => **Runnerrun.svg** or **_Runnerrun.svg** everything works fine...

Comment: This has nothing to do with D3, this is just how user agents deal with URIs in that CSS.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Oh I it has. Look at the name in the basic CSS (.runner), it will be loaded in all browsers, right. It is no problem to load the file with HTML in an <object> in all browsers, too! But in this very moment you use it in D3.js to load the file, it will not be compiled right. Maybe you should test it, if you think it would not be related?

Comment: Yes, you are correct: I didn't see the transition when I first read your question, sorry. The problem is clearly the transition: for starters, you should not use a transition here, since a transition tries to interpolate from a given start value to an ending value. Clearly, you cannot interpolate from an URI to another URI, it makes no sense. So, D3 is trying to interpolate the numbers, from `0804_0537` to `0805_0537`. At the first frame of the transition the value is `804.9576754956776_536.9717661381104` and the code crashes. Funnily enough, I cannot reproduce that number interpolation...

Comment: ... neither in V4 nor v5: in my attempts the interpolation is doing what it is expected to do: changing to the second value at the very first frame of the transition (which, obviously, makes the transition irrelevant). So, it would be nice if you could set up an [MCVE], so I could cache the values for each frame.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I would not have expected d3.js to interpolated any URL anyway, this does not make sense for me. Without the numbers the transition works smoothly as an easy kind of timer. That's why I used it. You can take this fiddle which fires the errors e.g. in Chrome https://jsfiddle.net/hirschferkel/L092a3fo/6/

Comment: I believe you missed my point: you **cannot** transition URIs. All transitions are interpolations! So, there is no reason for using the transition here, it's not transitioning anything, and you're relying only on the `delay` to change the background. So, just use a common `setTimeout` to change it.

Comment: O.k. ... it takes some time to get into d3.js .. but I fully understand your point now.